# how to get all data with special condition on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to get all data with condition discountPrice not nil?

if i have object like this inside my mongo db :

when i'm execute this query "db.products.find()", i get result like below :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456778"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "discountPrice" : 159200,
            "_id" : ObjectId("54697e689857572459444162"),
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("847446468"),
    "items" : [
        {
            "discountPrice" : nil,
            "_id" : ObjectId("54697e689857572459444162"),
        }
    ]
}
```

how to get result like this :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("123456778"),
        "items" : [
            {
                "discountPrice" : 159200,
                "_id" : ObjectId("54697e689857572459444162"),
            }
        ]
    }
```

how do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$ne` operator to match values that are "not equal" to `null`:

```
db.products.find( { "items.discountprice": { "$ne": null } } )
```

I've changed your reference of `nil` to `null` because `nil` is not a [valid BSON type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/). I'm assuming that you are using ruby which uses `nil` in favor of `null`. Using your mongodb drivers, I think you'll still be able to actually supply the value `nil`, but in this language agnostic post the correct value would be `null`.

Comment: still not found anything, $ne: null not result

Comment: @sholehs - I don't really understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: if i execute : db.products.find( { "items.discountprice": { "$ne": null } } )

i'm not get data, if i'm try db.products.find( { "items.discountPrice": { "$ne": 159200 } } )

this is work properly, but not work with null value

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
 db.products.find({'items.discountPrice':{ '$ne': null }});
```

more info on queries can be found here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Edit: updated example with using null.

Comment: discountPrice inside items

Comment: @sholehs - try using `$ne` (not equal) instead of `$nin` (not in)

Comment: A small suggestion that makes it easier for the future. Try using null instead of nil, or equal the nil to an int (0)

Comment: still not found anything, $ne: null not result

Comment: This should work just find, forgot to add the brackets around '$ne'